# Is possible to access to pod information from inside the container?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment configured with 5 replicas. I want to know inside each running container the name of the pod replica.

When I execute:

```
kubectl get pods

NAME                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-581957695-cbjtm   1/1       Running   3          1d
test-581957695-dnv8s   1/1       Running   1          1d
test-581957695-fv467   1/1       Running   1          1d
test-581957695-m74lc   1/1       Running   0          1d
test-581957695-s6cx0   1/1       Running   1          1d
```

Is it possible to get the name "test-581957695-cbjtm" from inside the container?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use env vars to expose pod information to container.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use Kubernetes Downward API. Using the API, you can expose pod/container information inside your container via a VolumeFile or Environment Variables.
Currently, these are the pieces of information you can expose:

> - The node’s name
> - The Pod’s name
> - The Pod’s namespace
> - The Pod’s IP address
> - The Pod’s service account name
> - A Container’s CPU limit
> - A container’s CPU request
> - A Container’s memory limit
> - A Container’s memory request
>
> In addition, the following information is available through DownwardAPIVolumeFiles,
>
> - The Pod’s labels
> - The Pod’s annotations

For more information please see, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#the-downward-api